# PostSharp Recordable and SelectedItem

Tags: selecteditem, postsharp

I am using [Recordable] on one of my viewmodels

```
  [NotifyPropertyChanged]
  [Recordable(AutoRecord = false)]
  public class ListViewModelBase<TEntity> : MessageServiceAwareViewModelBase
```

which has a property

```
[NotRecorded]
public TEntity SelectedEntity
{
  get { return selectedEntity; }
  set
  {
    selectedEntity = value;
    NewEntity = default(TEntity);
    DeleteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    UndoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
  }
}
```

with the backing field

```
[Child]
[NotRecorded]
private TEntity selectedEntity;
```

I have bound a devexpress gridcontrol's

```
SelectedItem
```

to this property.

On Startup, the grid is not focused and SelectedEntity is null.
When I select a row, SelectedEntity is set and Undo becomes available, which is wrong in my opinion.
Looking into the UndoOperations, I find an entry for "set_SelectedEntity", which should not be the case.

I am not sure if the structure of my viewmodel classes plays a role:

I have VM1:VM2 that binds to the UI, VM2:VM3 for list-specific stuff and VM3 containing the Undo/Redo-commands.

The undo/redo works fine for the editing in the gridcontrol except for the selection of a grid row.

Any clues?

Comment: Could you share a sample reproducing this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by restructuring the viewmodels